# Django shorten query on save to ForeignKeyField

Tags: django

I have 2 models `Owners`, `Relationships`

**Owners**

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
```

**Relationships**

```
class Relationships(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relationship_owner')
    target_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relationship_target_owner')
```

To add rows to `Relationships`, I used below query.

```
owner1 = Owner.objects.filter(nickname='hide').first()
owner2 = Owner.objects.filter(nickname='john').first()
Relationships.objects.create(owner=owner1, target_owner=owner2)
```

It is pretty clear. But when I inspect on `django-debug-toolbar`, it queried to database 3 times.

1. Get `nickname=hide` from owners table.
2. Get `nickname=john` from owners table.
3. Insert into `hide` and `john` into relationship table.

I wonder that, is it a general way?

Or, Is there any clear way to performing above query?

Thanks!

Comment: you can get both the owners in a single query. Something like `Owner.objects.filter(nickname__in=['john', 'hide'])`

Comment: @NalinDobhal No I mean, in case of create `relationship`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having `ForeignKey` relationship to that model, you can use the following method:

```py
owner = Owner.objects.filter(nickname='hide').first()
owner2 = Owner.objects.filter(nickname='john').first()
owner.relationships_set.create(target_owner=owner2)
```

Comment: Works find. But it fetched to db 3 times yet.

Comment: And not `owner.relationships_set` but `owner.relationship_owner`. Because I set `related_name='relationship_owner'` to `Relationship` model's `owner` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```py
from django.db.models import Subquery

owner1 = Owner.objects.get(nickname='hide')
owner2 = Owner.objects.get(nickname='john')

Relationships.objects.create(
    owner=Subquery(owner1)),
    target_owner=Subquery(owner2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert `nickname` field to the primary key of `Owner`, **or** you use [**`to_field`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), then you can use it like this:

```
# If you are using to_field
class Relationships(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relationship_owner',to_field='nickname')
    target_owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='relationship_target_owner', to_field='nickname')

# usage
Relationships.objects.create(owner_id='nick', target_owner_id='john')
```